# Сортировка массива обьектов

Tags: java

Не получается отсортировать массив обьектов по возврастанию.
Нужно отсортировать переданный массив обьектов Person, но параметру возвраст (age). При этом, в переданных обьектах значение age может быть равно 0, а так же Person может быть null.

```
Person {
String name;
int age;
}
```

Какой должен быть порядок: сначала отсортированные по возврастанию обьекты с возврастом (кроме стандартного - 0) - [обьект16лет, обьект17лет, обьект0лет, обьект0лет, null, null].
**Подскажите, как это решить самым коротким и грамотным путем , на ваше мнение.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для краткой записи достаточно использовать [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) + [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```java
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Jack", 16), null, new Person("John", 0), new Person("Jeff", 17), null
));

persons.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(
    Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getAge() == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : p.getAge())
));

System.out.println(persons);
```

Результат:

```
[Jack 16 yrs, Jeff 17 yrs, John 0 yrs, null, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Person[] persons = {person0, person16, person0, null, null, person17};
        Arrays.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                // Если оба объекта null либо объекты идентичны (одинаковые ссылки), то объекты равны
                if (o1 == o2) {
                    return 0;
                }
                // Если первый объект null (второй не null, т.к. такое условие проверяолсь выше),
                // либо возраст первого объекта 0, то первый объект "больше" второго
                if (o1 == null || o1.age == 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
                // Если второй объект null (первый не null, т.к. такое условие проверяолсь выше),
                // либо возраст второго объекта 0, то первый объект "меньше" второго
                if (o2 == null || o2.age == 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
                // для остальных случаев определяем, что первый объект "больше" второго
                // если его возраст больше
                return o1.age - o2.age;
            }
        });
```